# how to measure round trip time for ARP request

Tags: python, time, arp

I did python script to send ARP request from host 1 to another hosts ( host 2, 3, … , host 64 ) and I received the reply and capture the traffic through Wireshrk.

```
 from scapy.all import *
 eth = Ether(src='00:00:00:00:00:01', dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
 arp = ARP(op=1, psrc="192.168.1.254", hwsrc="00:00:00:00:00:01",hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", pdst="192.168.1.192/26")
 flood = eth / arp
 sendp(flood)
```

i know the RTT is time for send ARP request and receive ARP reply But my misunderstanding how can I measure the RTT when I send 64 ARP request ?

Let we imagine some cases :

1-  Send 1 ARP request , and the information is like the below table , here I think RTT is 1 second because the time for send and receive the ARP is 1 second.

Time-----Sender--Receiver----Protocol--Type
0.000s----A--------broadcast---ARP--Request
1.000s----B--------A--------------ARP–-Reply

2-  Send 2 ARP request , and the information is like the below table , here I don't know how can I measure the RTT ?

Time----Sender---Receiver-------Protocol--Type
0.000s---A---------broadcast------ARP--Request
1.000s---B---------A-----------------ARP-–Reply
1.500s---A---------broadcast------ARP--Request
2.500s---C---------A-----------------ARP-–Reply

3-  Also I don't know how can I measure the RTT,  when I send 64 ARP request from host 1 to hosts 2,3,4 and so on .

Thank you.

Comment: Please submit your code to be helped.

Comment: Record the time when you send the ARP request, record the time when you receive the ARP response. Subtract the 2 timestamps to find the difference , that will be your RTT. Now - if you have a specific problem, please state clearly what the problem is, and post the code you need help with or have an issue wirth.

Comment: Thank you @nos , my problem how to measure RTT when i send 2 arp request or 3 arp request ? when i send 1 arp i Subtract the 2 timestamps to find the difference but what must i do when i send 2 or 3 or 4 ?

Comment: If you send out several ARP requests that look 100% exactly the same, then you can NOT match the request and responses, and you'll have a problem - don't do that. You need at least a reasonable timeout between sending the ARP requests.However if you send out several ARP requests for different IP addresses, store the timestamp in e.g. a map that is indexed by the "Target IP address" in the ARP request - when an ARP reply comes in, extract the "Sender IP Address" and look that up in your map.

Comment: @Ambitions i added the code

Comment: Ok @nos that mean i must store timestamp for each ARR packet , i am i right ?

Comment: @nos yes i send out several ARP requests for different IP addresses , Thank you